# accomplished in [accomplished an advanced education]

Tags: word-choice

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) Jack **accomplished** an advanced education. He doesn't know why I can't get a good job.

Is "accomplished" the right correct? Thank you.

Comment: Please use the "Edit" button to tell about the meaning you want. "Accomplished" is an okay word here, and there are other options.

Comment: You usually 'accomplish' a task, particularly a difficult one, not something that you receive like an education.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more natural to say:

- Jack has an advanced education
- Jack got an advanced education
- Jack acquired an advanced education
- Jack obtained an advanced education